# How to test asynchonous functions using sinon?

Tags: sinon

I have a class called PostController, and I trying to test the following function create:

```
class PostController {
  constructor(Post) {
    this.Post = Post;
  }

  async create(req, res) {
    try {
      this.validFieldRequireds(req);
      const post = new this.Post(req.body);
      post.user = req.user;
      ...some validations here
      await post.save();
      return res.status(201).send(message.success.default);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      const msg = err.name === 'AppError' ? err.message : 
      message.error.default;
      return res.status(422).send(msg);
    }
 }
```

My test class is:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import PostController from '../../../src/controllers/posts';
import Post from '../../../src/models/post';

describe('Controller: Post', async () => {
  it.only('should call send with sucess message', () => {
    const request = {
      user: '56cb91bdc3464f14678934ca',
      body: {
        type: 'Venda',
        tradeFiatMinValue: '1',
        ... some more attributes here
      },
    };
    const response = {
      send: sinon.spy(),
      status: sinon.stub(),
    };

    response.status.withArgs(201).returns(response);
    sinon.stub(Post.prototype, 'save');
    const postController = new PostController(Post);

    return postController.create(request, response).then(() => {
      sinon.assert.calledWith(response.send);
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" 
>       is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. 
>       (D:\projeto\mestrado\localbonnum-back-end\test\unit\controllers\post_spec.js)

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's because misuse of `sinon.stub`.

You've

```
sinon.stub(Post.prototype, 'save');
```

without telling what this stub will do, so in principle this stub will do nothing (meaning it returns `undefined`).
IDK, why you don't see other like attempt to await on stub.
Nevertheless, you should properly configuture 'save' stub - for example like this:

```
const saveStub = sinon.stub(Post.prototype, 'save');
saveStub.resolves({foo: "bar"});
```